# Why is $f_n (z)=\frac{1}{n}(e^{nz}-1)$ not injective?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

In our lecture notes it is stated the the function

$$
f_n (z)=\frac{1}{n}(e^{nz}-1),  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n=1,2,...
$$
is not univalent. Why is this? I draw the function in Mathematica and the function doesn't look not injective.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/562214/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not injective as a function of complex variable. For example $f_n(0) = 0 = f_n(2\pi i) $.

Comment: Arguably worse, $f_{n}(0) = f_{n}(2\pi i/n)$.... (+1)