# Push-forward of vector fields by local isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

I am studying *Riemannian Manifolds* by John Lee, and there is this lemma:

> **Lemma 7.2.** *The Riemann curvature endomorphism and curvature tensor are local isometry invariants. More precisely, if $\varphi:(M,g)\to(\widetilde{M},\tilde{g})$ is a local isometry, then*
>   $$\varphi^\ast\widetilde{Rm}=Rm;$$
>   $$\widetilde{R}(\varphi_\ast X,\varphi_\ast Y)\varphi_\ast Z=\varphi_\ast(R(X,Y)Z)\tag{1}.$$

But a general *local* isometry need not be a diffeomorphism, so how to make sense of the push-forward of vector fields (e.g. $\varphi_\ast X$) in this case? How to interpret equation $(1)$?

As far as I know, the push-forward is defined for a vector field $X$ on $M$ by
$$\varphi_\ast X:\widetilde{M}\to T\widetilde{M},\quad (\varphi_\ast X)_q=d\varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(q)}(X_{\varphi^{-1}(q)}),$$
so $\varphi^{-1}$ must exist and be smooth.

The proof of Lemma 7.2 is left as an exercise to the reader, so I don't have much clue to understand what the author meant.

Comment: I would assume that the key word here is "local". We know for a local isometry the map $\phi$ is regular (meaning the local coordinate representative has full rank) hence $\phi$ suitably restricted gives a diffeomorphism from an open set $\mathcal{U}$ to another corresponding open set $\mathcal{V} = \phi (\mathcal{U})$. This is the inverse function theorem for manifolds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@JamesS.Cook is right -- that equation is meant to be interpreted pointwise. It's confusing, because in that book I was using the same notation ($\varphi_*X$) for the global pushforward of a vector field and the pointwise pushforward (or differential) of $\varphi$ acting on a vector at a point. I've added a correction to my [online correction list](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/riemannian.html), clarifying that this is just a pointwise equation.

In the second edition of my *Smooth Manifolds* book, I've switched to the clearer notation $d\varphi_p(X)$ for the pointwise differential, and I reserve $\varphi_*X$ for situations in which there is a global pushforward map on vector fields (namely, when $\varphi$ is either a diffeomorphism or a Lie group homomorphism). I'll be switching to this convention in the second edition of *Riemannian Manifolds*, whenever it comes out (hopefully within the next two years).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'm hoping to guide a promising student through the Smooth Manifolds book next year, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the key word here is "local". We know for a local isometry the map $\phi$ is regular (meaning the local coordinate representative has full rank) hence $\phi$ suitably restricted gives a diffeomorphism. In particular, if $\phi$ has an injective differential at a point $p \in M$ then by the inverse function theorem for manifolds there exists an open set $\mathcal{U}\subseteq M$ containing $p$ and an open set $\mathcal{V} \subseteq \widetilde{M}$ for which $\phi|_{\mathcal{U}}: \mathcal{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ is a diffeomorphism. See page 79, Theorem 4.5 of John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* for a clear statement and proof of the inverse function theorem for manifolds. I couldn't find it in the text *Riemannian Manifolds* by Lee (although, perhaps it's in there somewhere)

So, how should we understand the push-forward? Well, in short, point-wise. Observe, locally, the push-forward does give vector fields on an open set and that is enough to calculate the local Riemann data. Indeed, globally we can have $M$ and $\widetilde{M}$ which are **not** diffeomorphic, yet, locally they are diffeomorphic. For example, [see this related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39142/36530)

This much we can say, if we have a bijection of $\psi:M \rightarrow \widetilde{M}$ and $\psi_*$ is injective at each $p \in M$ then $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism. We just weave together the local inverses to show smoothness of $\psi^{-1}$.