# Question on vector fields along maps (need a quick sanity check)

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $f: M \to N$ be some smooth map between smooth manifolds.

If $V$ is a vector field, that is, a smooth map $V: N \to TN$ then $V$ is a vector field *along $f$* if the projection $\pi: TN \to N$ is such that $\pi (V(m)) = f(m)$ for all $m \in M$.

If ${\partial \over \partial x_i} f(m)$ is non zero then $V (m) := (f(m), {\partial \over \partial x_i} f(m))$ is a vector field along $f$ as $\pi (V(m)) = f(m)$.

> Now my question is: what happens if ${\partial \over \partial x_i}
>  f(m) = 0$? Can I choose $V$ to be anything other than $0$? It seems to
>    me that the answer might be yes since the zero vector is part of any
>   vector space.

I started to wonder about this as I was trying to come up with a vector field along a map $(f_1,f_2): \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ mapping $0$ to $0$ and such that ${\partial^n \over \partial x^n}f_i(0) \neq 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$. Furthermore, I want the vector field to be non zero and such that the linear span of the vector field contain the linear span of ${\partial \over \partial x}f(x)$ on some neighbourhood of $x_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: If $V$ is a vector field on $N$ then I'm not sure what you mean by $V(m)$ where $m \in M$. Perhaps that is supposed to read $V(f(m))$ in the second paragraph. Then $\pi( V(f(m))) = f(m)$ which would mean $V$ is a vector field along the image of $f$. I don't believe the $V(m) = (f(m), \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(m))$ defines a vector field on the image since there is no reason to suppose $f$ is globally injective. That is, $f(m_1)=f(m_2)$ is possible for $m_1 \neq m_2$ and these distinct points may well bring distinct tangents (you can't attach both to the point $f(m_1)$)

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thank you very much for your comment, it is very helpful. I didn't know how to resolve the point you mention but the answer has helped me do so: the vector field is restricted to some open set  $U \subset M$. So I suppose for $U$ small enough $f$ will be injective on $U$.

Comment: @a student often it is the case that if $U$ is small enough then $f$ restricted to $U$ is injective, but, if $f$ is constant then we'd have an insurmountable problem. Fortunately, the condition that the derivative of $f$ at $p$ be nonzero is sufficient to give a local inverse. It's funny this comes up again, just the other day I answered http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367605/36530 and I think you'll find Jack Lee's answer useful there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's make sure we're clear about the definitions. A ***vector field on $N$*** is a continuous map $V\colon N\to TN$ such that $V(n)\in T_nN$ for each $n\in N$. A ***vector field along $f$*** is a continuous map $W \colon M \to TN$ such that $W(m) \in T_{f(m)}N$ for each $m\in M$.

If $V$ is a vector field on $N$, then $V$ is not, as you claimed, a vector field along $f$; but it can be used to *define* a vector field along $f$ by setting $W=V\circ f$: In other words, $W(m) = V_{f(m)}\in T_{f(m)}N$ for each $m\in M$. But there are also plenty of vector fields along $f$ that are not of this type.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f(m)$. Perhaps you mean to choose coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on some open subset $U\subseteq M$; if so, then $V(m) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f(m)$ does define a vector field along the restricted map $f|_U$. One way to make this precise is by letting $V(x^1,\dots,x^m)$ be the velocity vector at $t=0$ of the curve
$$
t\mapsto f(x^1,\dots, x^i+t,\dots, x^n).
$$
This is a well-defined vector field along $f|_U$, regardless of whether $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f(m)=0$ for some $m$ or not.

To answer your last question, if $f = (f_1,f_2)\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ is a smooth map such that $f(0)=0$, and $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}f(0)\ne 0$, then Taylor's theorem implies that $(f_1(x),f_2(x)) = t^n (W_1(x),W_2(x))$ for some smooth functions $W_1,W_2$ such that $W_1(0)$ and $W_2(0)$ are not both zero. You can think of $(W_1,W_2)$ as a vector field along $f$, and as such, it satisfies the condition you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the expression $(f_1(x),f_2(x)) = t^n (W_1(x),W_2(x))$ do you not have to assume the first $n$ derivatives of both $f_i$ vanish? If not then the Taylor series of $f_i$ contains $t^k$ terms for $k < n$ and then it seems to me that $W_i(x)$ would contain a term of the form $t^{-j}$ for some $j$. But then it wouldn't be smooth on $\mathbb R$. But maybe my understanding that the $W_i$ are just the Taylor series is wrong.

Comment: The partial derivative I wrote is a mistake I made as I hastily generalised from $\mathbb R^n$ to general smooth manifolds.

Comment: @astudent: Sorry, I should have said that $n$ is the smallest integer such that the $n$th derivative of $f$ is nonzero at $0$.  Fixed now.

Comment: I'm sorry for keeping on asking questions but I have a question about the notation (I'm new to differential geometry): when you write "then $V(m) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f(m)$ does define a vector field..." are you using this notation to mean $V(m) = (f(m), \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}f(m))$? I am wondering because the vector field maps into the tangent bundle and the points there are pairs of vectors.

Comment: @astudent: On $\mathbb R^n$ (or any finite-dimensional vector space), the tangent space at each point is canonically identified with the vector space itself. Thus a vector field on a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is just the same as a map from the subset to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's not 100% clear to me yet. In the meantime I realised that we can obtain a vector field along $f$ even more easily: we can just use $W_1(x) = {\partial^n \over \partial x^n} f_1(x)$ and $W_2(x) = f_2' (x)$. Since by the assumption ${\partial^n \over \partial x^n} f_1(0) \neq 0$ there exists a neighbourhood of $0$ on which $W_1$ is nonzero. On this neighbourhood $(W_1,W_2)$ will be a nonzero vector field containing the partial derivatives of $f$! Yay! \\(^o^)/ (I realise it's almost the same as what you wrote but just a wee bit shorter)