# Example of map that is locally diffeomorphism at every point but not a differomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

What is such an example?

I am trying to understand the difference between being locally diffeomorphic at every point and globally a diffeomorphic.

thank you

Comment: Any covering map works, such as the map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ given by $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A local diffeomorphism of Euclidean space that is not a diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39142/a-local-diffeomorphism-of-euclidean-space-that-is-not-a-diffeomorphism)

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto (e^x\cos y, e^x \sin y)$